# Android life cycle and home button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have simple android application with two activities:

- First main activity containts ViewPager with tab navigation (3 tabs, one fragment per tag). One of these fragments is ListFragment which is a contact book (images and text).
- Second activity represents contact details.

When user clicks on listview contact row then the second activity is started with contact details. Back buttom from this activity works fine, when clicked then main acitivity is resumed immediately. But I have problem with home button (up button in action bar). When it's clicked then main activity is not resumed but created again and it consume lot of time (even 800ms).

Manifest card activity config with home button fragment:

```
<activity
     android:name="com.sampleapp.activity.CardActivity"
     android:label="@string/title_activity_card"
     android:parentActivityName="com.sampleapp.activity.MainActivity">
     <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
     <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
          android:value="com.sampleapp.activity.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Is there any way to resume main acitivity from stack (if it is there) when home button occur?

Comment: How are you returning to the main activity? Are you using `NavUtils. navigateUpFromSameTask()`? or some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This It may help you to get activity in front**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,YourActivityName.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Actually this may not be what you want. Unless you finish the current activity, this will just move the main activity to the foreground thereby putting the current activity underneath it. This means that pressing the BCK button on your main activity will now show the activity that you just left.

Answer (score 0):

The `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` flag will probably behave better then the accepted answer's flag:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,YourActivityName.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

From the docs:

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to
>   be cleared before the activity is started.